# How can I show progressBar when audio/recording is started?

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

I use the following for playing and recordingL

```
AudioRecorder recorder; 
recorder.setOutputUrl(<file path...>); 
recorder.record();
```

and

```
AudioPlayer player;
player.setInputUrl(...);
player.play();
```

How can I show progress bar for tham in QML?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__multimedia__mediaplayer.html) you can take advantage of the durationChanged() and positionChanged() signals to drive a ProgressBar. I couldn't find any references to AudioPlayer in the Cascades API.